# how to index mongomapper 1 to many with sunspot / solr as its an objectId filed and not an integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, solr, mongomapper, sunspot

I have a mongomapper product and a category model and a category has many products.

I am trying to use facets using the categories like this. (seems to work in AR)

```
searchable do
      text :name
      integer :category_id, :references => ::Category
    end
```

Problem is category_id is an ObjectId not integer so i get :

undefined method `to_i' for BSON::ObjectId(....   error when trying to index products.

Any one done this before ?

Any ideas how to do this ?

Thanks 
rick

Comment: I don't know offhand, but I'm voting this up to keep it relevant as it's a good question.

Comment: is there a specific reason for doing `integer :category_id` instead of `ObjectId :category_id`?